# Problem on Hill's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the equation 
$$
\frac{d^2\space y} { d\space x^2}+ y\sin^2 (100t)=0
$$
 has only bounded solutions.

I was trying to prove $|y(1)(p) + y(2)(p)|< 2$ where $y(1)$ and $y(2)$ are $2$ linearly independent 
solutions and $p$ is the period of $\sin^2 (100t)$.

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: oops...I meant |y(1)(p)+y(2)`(p)|<2.

Comment: $t=x$? Isn't it?

Comment: Yes,I meant that

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with [Floquet theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory)?